# Alfresco injection bean

Tags: java, javabeans, alfresco

I know how to inject bean into Java web script. It's quite simple:

```
<bean id="webscript.ru.mycompany.maypackage.myclass.get"
    class="ru.mycompany.maypackage.myclass"
    parent="webscript">             
    <property name="properties">
            <ref bean="global-properties"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But it's not working for custom java class, **variable properties is null** :(

```
<bean id="myclass"
    class="ru.mycompany.maypackage.myclass">                
    <property name="properties">
            <ref bean="global-properties"/>
    </property>
</bean>

public class myclass
{
    private Properties properties;
    public myclass()
    {

    }

    public void setProperties(Properties properties) 
    {
        this.properties = properties;       
    }
}
```

**What should I do?**

Comment: How do you call myclass instance? Perhaps, you call your myclass through "new" operator.

Comment: yes, new myclass().mymethod()

Answer (score 1):

You should inject myclass bean into other bean(where you want to use it)  the same way as you inject global-properties in myclass class. Spring IOC know nothing about myclass if you create instance through "new" operator

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement **ApplicationContextAware** so you'll get

```
public class myclass implements ApplicationContextAware
```

or you'll need autowiring, like:

```
@Value("${custom.url}")
protected String url;
```

Comment: Thank you, but MyClass is on repo side, not is on share side